# Django - Fabric & collecstatic - can't open file 'manage.py'

Tags: python, django, production-environment, fabric

I'm begining to use Fabric for a Django production server.
Here is my `fabfile.py`

```
from fabric.api import *
env.hosts = ['me@myserver.net']
def srefresh():
  with path('~me/myproject'):
    run('python manage.py collectstatic')
    sudo('apachectl restart')
```

And here is the output

> $ fab srefresh
>   [me@myserver.net] Executing task 'srefresh'
>   [me@myserver.net] run: python manage.py collectstatic
>   [me@myserver.net] out: python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong ?
(not sure I'm using the `with` context manager well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's quite clearly written in the [docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.0/api/core/context_managers.html). `fabric.context_managers.path` alters the PATH variable. `fabric.context_managers.cd` can be used to change the remote directory. So in your case:

```
def srefresh():
    with cd('~me/myproject'):
        run('python manage.py collectstatic')
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Right, it's been a little confusion

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
run('python ./manage.py collectstatic')
```

Also check the permissions of manage.py

Comment: Same thing, `python manage.py collectstatic` is working fine when runned manually on the good directory (that is `~me/myproject`)